# Extract ET by masking features

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, masking

I have asked the question before also. My code is for extracting ET for odisha using mask of water and build up. So I write the code. But the value before and after masking is same. I don't understand where is the error. If there is any other option to extract data by mask.

My code is below:

```
/**** Start of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. ****/
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-tbhattacharya/assets/odisha");
/***** End of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. *****/

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2').filterDate('2016-12-31', '2017-04-30').filterBounds(roi).sort('CLOUD_COVER');
print(collection);
var outline = ee.Image().byte().paint({
  featureCollection: roi,
  color: 1,
  width: 3
});
Map.addLayer(outline, {pallette: ['black']},"Study Area");
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);
function addNDBI(image){
  var ndbi = image.expression(
    "((SWIR-NIR)/(SWIR+NIR))",{
      'NIR'    : image.select('SR_B5'),
      'SWIR'    : image.select('SR_B6')
    }).rename('ndbi');
    return image.addBands(ndbi);
}
var LC09ndbi = collection.map (addNDBI);
var LC09ndbi = LC09ndbi.select('ndbi').median();
var clipndbi = LC09ndbi.clip(roi);
Export.image.toDrive({
  image : clipndbi,
  folder : 'Landsat 09',
  description : 'NDBI_L9',
  crs : 'EPSG:4326',
  region : roi,
  scale :30,
  maxPixels: 3784216672400,
  fileFormat : 'GEOTIFF',
  formatOptions : {
    cloudOptimized :true
    
  }
  
  
})
/***** End of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. *****/
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA').filterDate('2016-12-31', '2017-04-30').filterBounds(roi).sort('CLOUD_COVER');
print(collection);
var outline = ee.Image().byte().paint({
  featureCollection: roi,
  color: 1,
  width: 3
});
Map.addLayer(outline, {pallette: ['black']},"Study Area");
Map.centerObject(roi, 8);
function addMNDWI(image){
  var mndwi = image.expression(
    "((Green-SWIR)/(Green+SWIR))",{
      'Green'    : image.select('B3'),
      'SWIR'    : image.select('B6')
    }).rename('mndwi');
    return image.addBands(mndwi);
}
var LC09mndwi = collection.map (addMNDWI);
var LC09mndwi = LC09mndwi.select('mndwi').median();
var clipmndwi = LC09mndwi.clip(roi);
Export.image.toDrive({
  image : clipmndwi,
  folder : 'Landsat 09',
  description : 'MNDWI_L9',
  crs : 'EPSG:4326',
  region : roi,
  scale :30,
  maxPixels: 3784216672400,
  fileFormat : 'GEOTIFF',
  formatOptions : {
    cloudOptimized :true
    
  }
  
  
})
var threshold = clipndbi.gt(0.1);
var threshold1= clipmndwi.gt(0.055)
var mask1 = threshold.updateMask(threshold);
var mask2 = threshold.updateMask(threshold1);
var mask3 = mask1.blend(mask2)

var ET = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD16A2").filterBounds(roi).filterDate('2016-01-01', '2019-12-31');

var s2_masked = ET.map (function(image){
  // Here comes the same code as for a single Image, 
  // but only replacing the specific variable `test_image` from before with the
  // general parameter `image` that we just specified as the parameter of
  // this function
 return image.updateMask(mask3.unmask().not());
})

//var ET1 = collection.map (ET);
//var ET2 = ET1.updateMask(mask3.unmask().not());

Map.addLayer(ET, {}, 'Output Image');
//var ET2 = ET1.updateMask(mask3.unmask().not());
//Map.addLayer(ET2, {}, 'Output Image')
//var ET1 = mask3.not();
//var output = ET2.mask(ET1);
//Map.addLayer(output, {}, 'Output Image')

var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12)
var years = ee.List([2016,2017,2018,2019])
// Store ET1 as a FeatureCollection instead of an ImageCollection
var ET1 = ee.FeatureCollection(
  years.map(function(y){
    return months.map(function(m){
      var w = s2_masked.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month')).select('ET').mean().reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), roi , 500)
       // Convert the dictioanry `w` to a Feature (no geometry), set all geometries, and return it
      return ee.Feature(null, w)
        .set('month', m)
        .set('year', y)
        .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1));
    });
  }).flatten()
);
  print(ET1)
```

Comment: What is “ET”?  What error is the code that you have presented giving you?